# Is there a way to get types for @pixi/app (and other pixi modules)

Tags: javascript, typescript, pixi.js

Im currently setting up a project using pixiJs and typescript, i want to use the `@pixi/app` and other pixi packages so that the final bundle is smaller, my current bundle is `387 KiB` (without my own code), using `@pixi/app`, `@pixi/loaders` and `@pixi/sprite` my bundle is `211 KiB` which is `176 KiB` smaller.

The problem is there is no typing that i could find for `@pixi/anyPackage`, is there a way to get the typing in a way that is not super hacky or do i have to choose between a big bundle and types ?

Comment: From what i can see, pixi is entirely [written in TS and open-source](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/tree/dev/packages/loaders/src)?

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes,  but the packages don't have the types included.

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly searched around and found [this](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-typescript). Does it suit your needs?

However, please note that this package isn't for v5.

`Note This repository is not intended for v5.x which ships with its own generated declarations.`